# Xamarin Forms: How to add the scroll-viewer to entire page in uwp

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, scrollview, uwp-xaml

hello friends i want to add the scroll-viewer to entire page when user Restore down or decreases the application height or width then the scroll-viewer should enable. so that user can move the form using scroll-viewer.
Thanks in advance.

when i am passing the scroll-viewer  it not enable when i am Restore Down or decreases the application height

```
<ScrollViewer>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1000" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="27*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="19*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="38*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="57*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="38*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="56*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="18*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="18*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="12*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="12*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="11*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="16*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="54*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventorySemiBoldFont}" Text="Personal Information" FontSize="16" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="43,14,44,45" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Text="Prefix" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="43,56,37,3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"    />


    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Margin="49,51,16,9" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1"  CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30" >
        <ComboBox Padding="8 0 0 0" extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Width="200" BorderBrush="Transparent"  BorderThickness="0" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="13" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" UseLayoutRounding="True" TabIndex="1" Name="userPrefix" PlaceholderText="Select Prefix" PlaceholderForeground="#414042" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
            <x:String>Mr</x:String>
            <x:String>Mrs</x:String>
            <x:String>Miss</x:String>
        </ComboBox>
    </Border>



    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Padding="0"  Text="First Name" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="64,51,0,10" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Height="30"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1"  CornerRadius="5" Width="220" Margin="21,50,0,8" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <TextBox extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" MaxLength="20" Padding="6" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" TabIndex="2" FontSize="13" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" PlaceholderText="Enter First Name" Width="220"   Name="userFirstName" Text="" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" TextChanging="UserFirstName_TextChanging" Margin="0,0,0,-1" />
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Text=""   Name="FirstNameError" FontSize="11" Foreground="red" Margin="21,82,0,54" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
 <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Padding="0"  Text="First Name" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="64,51,0,10" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Height="30"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1"  CornerRadius="5" Width="220" Margin="21,50,0,8" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <TextBox extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" MaxLength="20" Padding="6" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" TabIndex="2" FontSize="13" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" PlaceholderText="Enter First Name" Width="220"   Name="userFirstName" Text="" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" TextChanging="UserFirstName_TextChanging" Margin="0,0,0,-1" />
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Text=""   Name="FirstNameError" FontSize="11" Foreground="red" Margin="21,82,0,54" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Padding="0" Text="Middle Name" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="44,48,7,6" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="3"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Margin="38,46,22,14" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="3"  Height="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBox extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" MaxLength="20" Padding="8 6 6 6" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" TabIndex="3" PlaceholderText="Enter Middle Name" Text=""  Name="userMiddleName" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextChanging="UserMiddleName_TextChanging" Margin="0,0,0,-4" Width="200" />
    </Border>

    <TextBlock Text="*" Foreground="Red" Margin="40,12,120,19" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Padding="5,0,0,0" Text="Last Name" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="46,16,16,15" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Margin="49,18,16,12" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"   BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1"  CornerRadius="5" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <TextBox  extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" MaxLength="20" Padding="6" BorderBrush="Transparent"  BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" TabIndex="4" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" PlaceholderText="Enter Last Name" Height="30" Text="" Name="userLastName"  Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  RequestedTheme="Default" UseLayoutRounding="False" TextChanging="UserLastName_TextChanging" Margin="0,0,-2,-4" />
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Text="" Name="LastNameError" FontSize="11" Foreground="red" Margin="49,49,0,55" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>



    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Text="Gender" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="57,19,26,17" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="4"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Margin="21,10,0,14" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1" CornerRadius="5" Width="220">
        <ComboBox Padding="5 0 0 0" extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Light" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" AllowDrop="True"   Name="userGender" TabIndex="5"  Header="" PlaceholderForeground="#414042" PlaceholderText="Select Gender" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="6"  Grid.Row="4" Width="220" Height="38" Margin="0,0,0,-1">
            <x:String>Male</x:String>
            <x:String>Female</x:String>
            <x:String>Prefer not to say</x:String>
        </ComboBox>
    </Border>

    <TextBlock Text="*" Foreground="Red" Margin="44,10,0,23" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="13" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Email" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="51,16,31,17" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Margin="38,14,22,16" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1" CornerRadius="5">
        <TextBox extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" MaxLength="50" Padding="6" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" PlaceholderText="Enter Email" TabIndex="6" Text="" Height="30" Name="userEmail"  Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextChanging="UserEmail_TextChanging" Margin="0,0,-2,-4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Text="" Name="EmailError" FontSize="11" Foreground="red" Margin="38,47,0,55" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

    <TextBlock Text="*" Foreground="Red" Margin="41,10,0,23" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="40" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Password" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Padding="5 0 0 0" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="46,14,57,19" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <!--<PasswordBox  TabIndex="7" Height=" 20" Width=" 180"    Name="userPassword" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="49,12,0,16" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />-->
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Margin="49,13,16,17"  Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1" CornerRadius="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBox extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" MaxLength="20" Padding="6" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" PlaceholderText="Enter Password" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" TabIndex="7" Text="" Height=" 20"   Name="userPassword" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextChanging="UserPassword_TextChanging" Margin="0,-2,-1,-2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Border>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="wrap" Text="" Name="PasswordError" FontSize="11" Foreground="red" Margin="49,44,0,25" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Text="Select Role" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="68,19,277,7" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand"  Margin="21,10,0,13" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1" CornerRadius="5" Width="220" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ComboBox Padding="5 0 0 0" extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" SelectedValuePath="rid" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Light" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" TabIndex="8"  Name="userRoleId" Header="" PlaceholderForeground="#414042" PlaceholderText="Select Role" Width="220" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="5" GotFocus="UserRoleId_GotFocus" Margin="0,-10,0,-2">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Name ="roleName" Text="{Binding rname}" Tag="{Binding rid}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Text="" Name="RoleError" FontSize="11" Foreground="red" Margin="21,52,0,31" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <TextBlock Text="*" Foreground="Red" Margin="44,13,0,20" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="13"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Organization" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="51,19,31,14" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="5"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand"  Margin="38,13,22,17" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1" CornerRadius="5">
        <ComboBox Padding="5 0 0 0" extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" SelectedValuePath="rid" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Light" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" TabIndex="8"  Name="cmbOrganization" Header="" PlaceholderForeground="#414042" PlaceholderText="Select Organization" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="5"  Margin="-1,-13,-1,1" GotFocus="CmbOrganization_GotFocus">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Name ="OrganisationName" Text="{Binding name}" Tag="{Binding id}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Text="" Name="OrganizationError" FontSize="11" Foreground="red" Margin="40,48,0,34" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>



    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventorySemiBoldFont}" Padding="0" Text="Contact Information" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="16" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="43,6,50,10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  />

    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Padding="0" Text="Street Address" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="43,13,38,17" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Margin="49,18,16,12" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1" CornerRadius="5">
        <TextBox extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" MaxLength="100" Padding="8 6 6 6" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" PlaceholderText="Enter Street Address" TabIndex="12" Name="userAddress" Text="" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="201" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,-4" />
    </Border>


    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Text="City" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="44,14,32,5" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="7"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="7" Margin="38,10,22,10"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1" CornerRadius="5">
        <ComboBox Padding="5 0 0 0" extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" TabIndex="11"  FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}"   Header="" Name="userCity" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CityList}" PlaceholderText="Select City" PlaceholderForeground="#414042" FontWeight="Light" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="7"  Tapped="LoadCities" Margin="0,-6,-2,-2">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CityData" >
                    <TextBlock Name="{x:Bind cityId}" Text="{x:Bind cityName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Text=""   Name="CityError" FontSize="11" Foreground="red" Margin="44,44,0,17" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="183" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />




    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Padding="0" Text="State" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="64,13,12,24" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="7" Grid.RowSpan="2"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Margin="21,10,0,10" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="7"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1" CornerRadius="5" Width="220" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ComboBox Padding="5 0 0 0" extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Light" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" TabIndex="10"  Header="" Width=" 220" Name="userState" ItemsSource="{x:Bind StateList}" PlaceholderText="Select State" PlaceholderForeground="#414042" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="7" SelectionChanged="GetCityList" Tapped="LoadStates" Margin="0,-11,0,-2" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:StateData" >
                    <TextBlock Name="{x:Bind StateId}" Text="{x:Bind StateName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Border>

    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Padding="0" Text="Middle Name" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="44,48,7,6" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="3"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Margin="38,46,22,14" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="3"  Height="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBox extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" MaxLength="20" Padding="8 6 6 6" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" TabIndex="3" PlaceholderText="Enter Middle Name" Text=""  Name="userMiddleName" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextChanging="UserMiddleName_TextChanging" Margin="0,0,0,-4" Width="200" />
    </Border>
<TextBlock  Text="Country" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="43,10,39,14" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Grid.Column="3" Margin="49,14,16,6" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1" CornerRadius="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ComboBox Padding="5 0 0 0" extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Light" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" TabIndex="9"   Name="userCountry" Canvas.ZIndex="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CountryList}"  PlaceholderText="Select Country" PlaceholderForeground="#414042" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="7" SelectionChanged="GetStateList" Tapped="ClearError" Margin="0,0,-2,-2">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CountryData">
                    <TextBlock Name="{x:Bind CountryId}" Text="{x:Bind CountryName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Border>

    <TextBlock Text="" Name="CountryError" FontSize="11" Foreground="red" Grid.Column="3" Margin="46,42,0,17" Grid.Row="7"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <TextBlock Text=""  Name="StatesError" FontSize="11" Foreground="red" Margin="25,41,83,17" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="7" Grid.RowSpan="2"  />


    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Text="ZIP" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="64,17,57,16" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="8" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Margin="21,17,0,11" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1" CornerRadius="5" Width="220" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBox extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" MaxLength="6" Padding="6" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="13" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" InputScope="Number" PlaceholderText="Enter ZIP Code" TabIndex="13" Height="30"  Width="220" Name="userZip" Text="" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextChanging="UserZip_TextChanging"  />
    </Border>
    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Padding="0" Text="Phone Number" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="44,16,37,21" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="8" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <Border extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Margin="38,18,22,12" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E1E1E1" CornerRadius="5" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <TextBox  extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" MaxLength="13" Padding="6" FontSize="13" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}"  TabIndex="14" PlaceholderText="Enter Phone Number" Height="30" Name="userPhone" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextChanging="UserPhone_TextChanging" Margin="0,0,-2,-4" />
    </Border>
         <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource inventorySemiBoldFont}" Text="Assign Department" FontSize="16" FontWeight="SemiBold" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="43,17,72,43" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />



        <Button extensions:Mouse.Cursor="Hand" Style="{StaticResource  AssignButtonStyle}" Margin="0,18,0,7" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventorySemiBoldFont}" FontSize="13"    TabIndex="15" x:Name="BtnAssign" Background="#00BFF3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0.1"    Content="ASSIGN" Foreground="White"    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1"  Click="SelectDepartment" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />


 <ScrollViewer MinWidth =" 1200"    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Margin="38,53,0,31" Grid.Row="11" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1">
            <controls:WrapPanel MinWidth =" 1200"   Orientation="Horizontal"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"      Name="SPSelectdedDepartment" Grid.Row="12" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="1310"  MaxWidth ="1357" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Your question is vague can you be more specific, I am totally confused here!

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply i want to add the scroll-viewer to entire page when i am Restore Down the application or decreases the application height or width then scroll viewer is enable.

Comment: So you always want your `ScrollViewer` to take full screen?

Comment: yes it should take full screen.

Comment: any idea ? :( ???

Comment: You might wanna add the whole page code here so I can take a look also i am removing the XF tag as it is irrelevant

Comment: now check i have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A ScrollViewer enables content to be displayed in a smaller area than its actual size. When the content of the ScrollViewer is not entirely visible, the ScrollViewer displays scrollbars that the user can use to move the content areas that is visible. The area that includes all of the content of the ScrollViewer is the extent. The visible area of the content is the viewport.

Please check ScrollViewer official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer)

> A ScrollViewer enables content to be displayed in a smaller area than its actual size. When the content of the ScrollViewer is not entirely visible, the ScrollViewer displays scrollbars that the user can use to move the content areas that is visible. The area that includes all of the content of the ScrollViewer is the extent. The visible area of the content is the viewport.

So, if the content size large than ScrollViewer actual size, the scrollbars will display. I found you have set the grid height as 1000, if the `ScrollViewer` height less than 1000, the ScrollViewer will vertical scrolling. For making sure the `ScrollViewer` fill the page content, you need set `ScrollViewer`  `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` as `Stretch`.

```
<ScrollViewer  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```